# Dar color a stacked icons en FontAwesome

Tags: css

como podria darle color a los iconos de forma independiente, quiero que el corazon sea de color amarillo y el circulo de color rojo, pero no me da. Traté con color pero tampoco

Gracias por leer

```css
.fa-circle {
  background: red;
}

.fa-heart{
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="far fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: deberías usar la propiedad `color` en lugar de `background` y quitar la clase `fa-inverse`

Comment: Blonfu muchas grascias, funciona tambien como indicas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si usas `before` puedes aplicar tanto `background` como `color`. Prueba:

```
.fa-circle:before {
    background: red;
    color: blue;
}

.fa-heart:before {
    background: yellow;
    color: blue;
}
```

A mi me quedó así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona! Que significa la clase before la puedo usar en mi pagina?

Comment: Que bien, si te sirvió puedes marcar mi respuesta como acertada. Tanto :before como :after son pseudoelementos de css y las puedes aplicar a cualquier elemento que desees. Lo que hace es insertar algo despues o antes del contenido seleccionado, en este caso el `i` con clase `fa-heart`. El fontawesome te inserta los íconos en estos pseudoelementos y para aplicarle estilos solo debes aplicarlo donde está el icono

Answer (score 0):

Alvamon6, solo debes cambiar el estilo de background a color.

```
.fa-circle
{
    color: red;
}

.fa-heart
{
    color: yellow;
}
```

Html

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="far fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Y el resultado quedaría así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No funciona en amarillo en el corazon